# SQL0670N The statement failed because the row size of the resulting table would have exceeded the row size limit

Tags: cloudant, dashdb, cloudant-sdp

When working with the Cloudant SDP, I have encountered the following error:

> SQL0670N  The statement failed because the row size of the resulting table would have exceeded the row size limit.

What does the error mean, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused because there is one or more key(s) in Cloudant with a very long string value.  The error gives a hint to the problem:

```
SQLERRMC=32677;;72156
```

This is saying that the table size limit is 32K (32677), but the create statement was trying to create a table with size 72K (72156).

The following options are available as work-arounds:

1. Identify and remove the problem attributes from the source dataset
2. Create a view on the source dataset that excludes the problem attribute

Unfortunately, this process may be trial-and-error if you have a lot of attributes in your documents.